# Error in output file

Tags: c, function, file

In an exercise, I need to read an input file like the following one:

```
# add # Jabuticaba # Fruto de jabuticabeira. Jabuticabeira.
# add # Vacilar # Não estar firme. Cambalear. Oscilar. Tremer.
# add # Jacapa # Pássaro brasileiro escuro, de bico branco.
# search # Jacapa
# search # Jabuticaba
# search # Jacapa
# search # Vacilar
# sort
```

Where each content is between `#`. First, there is the operation to be done: `Add` a word to the list, `search` for a word in the list and `sort` for sorting the list alphabetically. The second content is the word and the third content its respective meaning. For example, for the first line, what should be done is add the word "Jabuticaba" into a list which will be sorted alphabetically at the end of the file, with the operation `sort`. Remembering that I need to save the word's meaning too. For the informations (words and meanings), I created the following struct:

```
typedef struct
{
    char palavra[MAX]; //word
    char sign[MAX]; //meaning
}Item;
```

The struct has two contents: An array to store the word and an array to store its meaning.

For reading the file and know which operation I should do, I used the function `strtok` for storing only the string's contents that are betweem `#`. We can see the function that reads the file below:

```
void LeEntrada(FILE *entrada, FILE *saida, FILE *dicionario, ArvBin *raiz, Item info)
{
    char linha[MAX];
    int i;
    char marc[3] = "#";

    if(entrada == NULL)
    {
        printf("Erro ao abrir o arquivo.\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    for(i = 0; i < 8; i++) //Faz os passos linha por linha
    {
        fgets(linha, MAX, entrada);
        char *token;

        token = strtok(linha, marc);

        if(strcmp(token, " add ") == 0)
        {
            token = strtok(NULL, marc);
            strcpy(info.palavra, token);
            Insere_Arvore(raiz, info);

            token = strtok(NULL, marc);
            strcpy(info.sign, token);
            fprintf(saida, "add%s\n", info.palavra);
        }

        else if(strcmp(token, " search ") == 0)
        {
            token = strtok(NULL, marc);
            strcpy(info.palavra, token);
            printf("%s\n", info.palavra);
            printf("%s\n", info.sign);
            Consulta_Arvore(raiz, info);
            fprintf(saida, "search%s #%s\n", info.palavra, info.sign);
        }
    }
}
```

There are three files as parameters for the function: The input file, used to be read, an output file and a "dictionary" file. The output file will be used to write a kind of log in it. So, after each operation, I need to write in this file what just happened. For example:

```
add Jabuticaba
add Vacilar
add Jacapa
search Jacapa # Pássaro brasileiro escuro, de bico branco.
search Jabuticaba # Fruto de jabuticabeira. Jabuticabeira.
search Jacapa # Pássaro brasileiro escuro, de bico branco.
```

However, testing with the function I made, I get the followin result for the output file:

```
add Jabuticaba 
add Vacilar 
add Jacapa 
search Jacapa
 # Pássaro brasileiro escuro, de bico branco.

search Jabuticaba
 # Pássaro brasileiro escuro, de bico branco.

search Jacapa
 # Pássaro brasileiro escuro, de bico branco.

search Vacilar
 # Pássaro brasileiro escuro, de bico branco.
```

I don't know the reason why after the first `search`, there is a line break `\n` and why the word's meaning repeats. What I noticed is that it repeats the meaning of the last word added to the list, which in this case is "Jacapa".

I would like to know what is the reason for this behavior and if there is a way to solve this problem. Or if there is a better way to read this file.

Comment: I tried changing and it keeps with the same output

Comment: I guess your code, especially the parts you do not show, have some severe issues. But most notably, the newline at the end of the line is part of the string when reading with `fgets()`. You have to trim it manually, otherwise it will not match the version without newline when parsed from `add`.